# Angularjs + Spring jpa repository Many-to-one field is not saving

Tags: angularjs, jpa

I am using Angularjs, Spring jpa repository, hibernate. 
The problem is "Unable to save the id of the Customer in the order table."
table names: Order, CustomerGlobal
reference col name for Customer in Order table is customerGlobal_id.
Order belongs to a Customer. Order table has a customerGlobal_id field.

In the Entity (Order), I have defined

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false) @JsonIgnore
CustomerGlobal customerGlobal;
```

Order belongs to one Customer. If I specify a JoinColumn, hibernate is generating the column in the database. So, I think there is no issue there.
I have added Getter and Setter for the customerGlobal field.

I am using JPA repository, the interface is defined as follows:

```
public interface OrderRepo extends JpaRepository<Order, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Order> {
...
}
```

I am assuming that this would work fine too.

Here is the relevant part of the html:

```
 <select ng-options="convertToInt(customer.id) as customer.name for customer in c" class="form-control " name="customerGlobal" ng-model="req.customerGlobal" required></select>
```

This is part of a form which gets saved from the associated controller. The values for c are obtained by get request on load.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"XYZ","contactPerson":"ABC","mobile":"1111111111","email":"abc@adef.com",}]
```

This seems to be working fine. I get a dropdown list of the customers in the table.

When I save the form, customerGlobal_id and other field values are sent via POST but the customerGlobal_id does not get saved to the database.

This does not seem to be a very specific problem. This is a basic many-to-one relationship that is not getting saved. I am not completely familiar with Angularjs. So please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use Spring Data REST to expose the endpoints for your entities? Also can you give an example with an *actual* request?

Comment: Yes, using spring data rest with spring boot.

Comment: You have to set the CASCADE of the hibernate mapping

Comment: Actually the Customers are added on a separate screen prior to creation of orders, so maybe I don't have to use cascade and save the customer before saving the Order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save a relationship with spring rest, you shouldn't use the id of the entity, but the **reference url** of the entity. So let's say that you have a `Car` entity that has an association with a `Make` entity, and you want to set the make of the car. Here is what you should do:

**Step 1**. get the `Make` entity:

```
-get a specific `Make`: localhost:8080/makes/1

-get a a list of `Make`: localhost:8080/makes
```

and select the one you want:

```
{
  "name" : "Toyota",
  "country" : "Japan",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/makes/1"
    }
}
```

**Step 2**. Now insert / update a `Car` like this:

POST/PUT http://localhost:8080/cars/123

```
{
  "model" : "Corolla",
  "year" : "2006",
  "hp" : 95,
  "make" : "http://localhost:8080/makes/1"
}
```

and **NOT** like this:

```
{
  "model" : "Corolla",
  "year" : "2006",
  "hp" : 95,
  "make" : 1
}
```

Spring Data Rest understands the **reference url** of the entity.

Comment: Looks promising. Let me try it out. Thanks.

Comment: No luck. This is what is getting sent... _embedded: {,…}
_links: {self: {href: "http://localhost:8080/rest/data/orders{?page,size,sort}", templated: true},…}
customerGlobal: "http://localhost:8080/rest/data/customerGlobals/1"
page: {size: 20, totalElements: 10, totalPages: 1, number: 0}
I picked the reference url from ._links.self.href

Comment: <select ng-options="customer._links.self.href as customer.name for customer in c" name="customerGlobal" ng-model="req.customerGlobal" required=""><option value="string:http://localhost:8080/rest/data/customerGlobals/1" label="XYZ">XYZ</option></select>

Comment: @SrividyaSharma Give me the actual HTTP Request. I want to see what you are sending to the server.

Comment: Ok, got it working. I had to remove the @JsonIgnore from the CustomerGlobal entity. Can you explain why this is needed? Could not understand what you meant by actual HTTP request?

Comment: @SrividyaSharma I meant the HTTP Request that you made to the server so i could take a look at the body of the request. If my answered helped you then please accept my answer.

Comment: Accepted. Timely Help Appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When the same page is used for edit, the drop-down is not showing the Customer as  selected ( the customer who was selected & saved at the time of creation). Do you think I should raise a new question for this? If the solution is simple, please comment here itself. thanks.